# apic start command failing

Tags: strongloop, apiconnect

I am getting the following error while trying to start an application using

```
apic start
```

Here is error that I am getting.

```
E:\nodejs\ThinkIBM\inventory>apic start inventory-gw did not return a port in timeout.
Error: Service inventory-gw started but did not initialize within the timeout period. Dumping log buffer. 
2016-11-28T02:19:52.577Z pid:8084 worker:0 INFO strong-agent native addon missing, install a compiler 
2016-11-28T02:19:52.577Z pid:8084 worker:0 INFO strong-agent v2.0.4 profiling app 'microgateway' pid '8084' 
2016-11-28T02:19:52.593Z pid:8084 worker:0 INFO strong-agent[8084] started profiling agent 
2016-11-28T02:19:52.593Z pid:8084 worker:0 INFO supervisor starting (pid 8084)
2016-11-28T02:19:52.593Z pid:8084 worker:0 INFO strong-agent strong-agent using strong-cluster-control v2.2.3 
2016-11-28T02:19:52.593Z pid:8084 worker:0 INFO supervisor reporting metrics to `internal:` 
2016-11-28T02:19:52.608Z pid:8084 worker:0 INFO strong-agent not profiling, agent metrics requires a valid license. 
 2016-11-28T02:19:52.608Z pid:8084 worker:0 Please contact sales@strongloop.com for assistance. 
 2016-11-28T02:19:52.608Z pid:8084 worker:0 INFO supervisor size set to 1 2016-11-28T02:19:52.812Z pid:8084 worker:0 INFO supervisor started worker 1 (pid 3360) 
 2016-11-28T02:19:52.812Z pid:8084 worker:0 INFO supervisor resized to 1 2016-11-28T02:19:53.343Z pid:3360 worker:1 INFO strong-agent native addon missing, install a compiler 
 2016-11-28T02:19:53.343Z pid:3360 worker:1 INFO strong-agent v2.0.4 profiling app 'microgateway' pid '3360' 
 2016-11-28T02:19:53.343Z pid:3360 worker:1 INFO strong-agent[3360] started profiling agent 
    2016-11-28T02:19:53.655Z pid:3360 worker:1 Error: Fail to load environment variables:  { [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\nodejs\node_modules\apiconnect\node_modules\apiconnect-cli-pm\node_modules\microgateway\env.yaml'] 
    2016-11-28T02:19:53.655Z pid:3360 worker:1   errno: -4058, 2016-11-28T02:19:53.655Z pid:3360 worker:1   code: 'ENOENT', 2016-11-28T02:19:53.655Z pid:3360 worker:1   syscall: 'open',    2016-11-28T02:19:53.655Z pid:3360 worker:1   path: 'E:\\nodejs\\node_modules\\apiconnect\\node_modules\\apiconnect-cli-pm\\node_modules\\microgateway\\env.yaml' } 
 2016-11-28T02:20:08.531Z pid:3360 worker:1 Error: not able to perform the handshake with APIM, error: [Error: can not load default private key]           2016-11-28T02:20:08.766Z pid:3360 worker:1 INFO strong-agent not profiling, agent metrics requires a valid license. 
 2016-11-28T02:20:08.766Z pid:3360 worker:1 Please contact sales@strongloop.com for assistance
```

Any idea what am I missing here? Below is the details of my apic versions along with the extensions.

E:\nodejs\ThinkIBM\inventory>apic --ext-version

```
apiconnect: v2.3.6 (API Connect: v5.0.4.0)
 apiconnect-cli-apis 2.3.0 (6c13193ba5b19c2ad39af78d3ee5f2381f8057d9)
 apiconnect-cli-apps 2.4.0 (a3540f9879aac38b0a97dad171c82e037ce2545c)
 apiconnect-cli-auth 2.4.0 (963e1e2ccddd29ff8acdd21c9feb2cb5e9822cab)
 apiconnect-cli-catalogs 2.2.0 (1fcb9e8c7fec5f2aa560e94d6d127e32148954c4)
 apiconnect-cli-config 2.3.1 (ad1a8b9b05dc9cb425b66c850faf25df3dae6612)
 apiconnect-cli-create 2.4.0 (255a725517978dc1bd2d4fc96969163ff47849a1)
 apiconnect-cli-devapps 1.0.0 (1824077edaff6e4c794caf7d6f5b7012a459fcd6)
 apiconnect-cli-drafts 2.4.1 (da80ce686a8930bfc0cbfe82ced3ef6b93233b28)
 apiconnect-cli-edit 2.3.0 (cb1b808997652edec04916ce389eacb4796ee39c)
 apiconnect-cli-loopback 2.3.0 (6cb04654fae3b677af1faf423c6b177ddd90b6a7)
 apiconnect-cli-orgs 2.3.0 (b7e3b08ad93ecc4052990e335e60368e5fd2580e)
 apiconnect-cli-pm 2.2.0 (e43a7047c9ab4bc06f5d90c1cc7ce2b7a74a998b)
  microgateway 1.5.3 (386fe17a7c5a301abb8681e67ffec35a68093744)
   flow-engine 1.1.0
 apiconnect-cli-policies 1.3.0 (b01a4d033850ea46343b6f97545fcfef2ca7159f)
 apiconnect-cli-products 2.4.0 (b518c07e7cf2e64f88a585903d5d09e50afaccd2)
 apiconnect-cli-validate 2.2.0 (38be0972b4536069ccaa53c58571dd1d0cff82c1)
 apiconnect-cli-version-checker 1.2.0 (8541f810263a987dc2ac2857d856eb763a4c4324)
 plugins 3.2.1
```

Comment: Could you also supply the output of `apic --version` and `apic --ext-version`?

Comment: apiconnect: v2.3.6 (API Connect: v5.0.4.0)
apiconnect-cli-apis 2.3.0 
apiconnect-cli-apps 2.4.0 
apiconnect-cli-auth 2.4.0 
apiconnect-cli-catalogs 2.2.0 
apiconnect-cli-config 2.3.1 
apiconnect-cli-create 2.4.0 
apiconnect-cli-devapps 1.0.0 
apiconnect-cli-drafts 2.4.1 
apiconnect-cli-edit 2.3.0 
apiconnect-cli-loopback 2.3.0 
apiconnect-cli-orgs 2.3.0 
apiconnect-cli-pm 2.2.0 
microgateway 1.5.3 
flow-engine 1.1.0
apiconnect-cli-policies 1.3.0 
apiconnect-cli-products 2.4.0 
apiconnect-cli-validate 2.2.0 
apiconnect-cli-version-checker 1.2.0 
plugins 3.2.1

Comment: @MattHamann I have added the information as requested

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this. In between, I am on Windows 10.

1. Run the Windows Command Prompt by selecting

> "Run as Administrator"

2. `apic start` works like a charm
3. On non-Windows system, try to run "apic start" using

   `super user.sudo` `apic start`

or

```
sudo apic start
```

I guess, as an alternative, During the install of apiconnect try  using '--unsafe-perm' with the install command that might overrides these permissions related issues on Windows